# Plotting multiple tracks (sequence of 2D points) on an image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have multiple tracks (a sequence of 2D points) which I want to plot over an image. For instance, in the example below I have 10 tracks, each having its own set of 3 points. I iterate over all tracks and plot each one of them individually. Note, that all my tracks have the same number of points.

This works fine, but its slow. The problem is that when I have large number of tracks (when NUM_TRACKS is large ~ 1000s), it takes too long to loop over each trajectory and plot them individually. Is there a way to display all tracks using a single `plot` command?

```
NUM_PNTS = 3;
NUM_TRACKS = 10;
pnts = 400 * rand(NUM_PNTS, 2, NUM_TRACKS);

imshow('peppers.png');
hold on;
for idx = 1:NUM_TRACKS
    curr_pnts = pnts(:,:,idx);
    plot(curr_pnts(:,1), curr_pnts(:,2), '.-', 'Color',[1,1,1], 'LineWidth',2);
end
hold off;
```

Comment: What does "too long" mean? In the example above, even setting `NUM_TRACKS=5000` the plotting is complete in 3.4 seconds. (Matlab 14b)

Comment: Yes that's right. I am building an interactive GUI, so anything > 1sec is too long. I was just wondering if you can do this in a single plot command - since the line style/marker style is the same.

Comment: Perhaps I've find a solution speeding up the plot of the tracks, I've updated both the answer and the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

The most time consuming operation in your code is the loading of the image; try adding `tic & toc` (see the code below).

A possible solution could be to reshape the original `pnts` matrix to a `(N x M)` that is putting the set of track points one after all. In doing that, we also add between each set of points of a track a row of NaN.

The resulting matrix will look like:

```
 108.3056  226.8722
   58.8603  322.0754
  294.0138  161.5577
       NaN       NaN
    3.0982  155.5985
   86.1691  190.2200
  390.4753  116.3666
       NaN       NaN
  288.5506  352.9553
  192.4952  158.6255
   31.8394  256.8299
       NaN       NaN
  396.1230  149.1251
  278.0844  110.9723
  274.6267   13.7672
       NaN       NaN
```

Now we can call `plot` asking to directly plot the matrix

```
plot(m(:,1),m(:,2), '.-', 'Color',[0,0,0], 'LineWidth',2);
```

Because of the NaN inserted, the function will plot as many "segments" as the number of tracks.

This should speed up the plot.

I've updated the code in order to generate the new (N x M) matrix.
(for sure there is a smarter and more efficient way to do it)

**Updated code**

```
NUM_PNTS = 3;
NUM_TRACKS = 5000;
pnts = 400 * rand(NUM_PNTS, 2, NUM_TRACKS);

imshow('peppers.png');

tic
m=NaN(NUM_PNTS*NUM_TRACKS+NUM_TRACKS,2);
for i=1:NUM_TRACKS
    m(i+(NUM_PNTS)*(i-1):i+(NUM_PNTS)*(i-1)+NUM_PNTS,:)=[pnts(:,:,i);NaN(1, 2)];
end
plot(m(:,1),m(:,2), '.-', 'Color',[0,0,0], 'LineWidth',2);
hold off;
toc
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that's right, in the example I gave reading the image was taking some time to load. I am more concerned with the amount of time `plot` commands take in a loop when NUM_TRACKS is more in the range of 1000s. For instance, when NUM_TRACKS = 5000, my machine takes at least 4s to go over the `plot` loop.  Any ideas on how to write a single plot command rather than looping over each set of tracks?

Comment: Oh wow, I like this NaN solution a lot :) Thanks so much @il_raffa